# Cannot upload two of the same image files

Tags: php, file-upload

I have an issue with uploading the same image twice, but in different sizes. What I thought I could do was having one file input, where I choose the image. In the upload php file, I have two variables:

```
$img = $_POST["file"];
$imgThumbnail = $_POST["file"];
```

I have then created a function to upload images to my webpage in php. I call the functions twice after each other, but the second time the function is called, I get the error "No such file or directory.." - the first image is uploaded correctly, but the second is not because of this error. What am I doing wrong, when the file is actually the same?

```
// First time, normal size img
uploadNewsIMG($imgFile, $pathToUpload, $img_author, $img_text, $img_tags, 950, "false");
        
// Second time, thumbnail size img - ERROR IS HERE "No such file or directory.. etc."
uploadNewsIMG($imgFileThumbnail, $pathToUpload, $img_author, $img_text, $img_tags, 400, "true");
```

When uploading the second image, this is the line that gives me the "No such.." error:

```
$fileName = $fileIMG['tmp_name']; // <- THIS IS THE VARIABLE "$imgFileThumbnail"
$image_size = getimagesize($fileName); // <- ERROR HERE
```

*EDIT*
This is the function `uploadNewsIMG()`:

```
function uploadNewsIMG($fileIMG, $path, $author, $alt_text, $img_tags, $max_width, $thumbnail) {
        
        global $con;
        
        $realFileName = $fileIMG['name'];
        $fileName = $fileIMG['tmp_name'];
        

        $realFileName = str_replace("(", "", $realFileName);
        $realFileName = str_replace(")", "", $realFileName);

        $fileName = str_replace("(", "", $fileName);
        $fileName = str_replace(")", "", $fileName);
        
        $realFileName = strtolower($realFileName);
        

        $now = strtotime("now");
        
        if ($thumbnail != "true") {
        
            $targetFilePath = "../../" . $path . $now . "-" . $realFileName; 
            $img_source_link = $path . $now . "-" . $realFileName;
            
        } else {
        
            $targetFilePath = "../../" . $path . "thumb-" . $now . "-" . $realFileName; 
            $img_source_link = $path . "thumb-" . $now . "-" . $realFileName;
            
        }

        $targetFilePath = str_replace(" ","", $targetFilePath);
        $img_source_link = str_replace(" ","", $img_source_link);


        // Resize billedet
        $dimension = $max_width;
        

        $image_size = getimagesize($fileName);
        $mime   = $image_size['mime'];
        $width = $image_size[0];
        $height = $image_size[1];

        $ratio = $width / $height;
        

        if ($ratio > 1) {
            $new_width = $dimension;
            $new_height = $dimension / $ratio;
        } else {
            $new_height = $dimension;
            $new_width = $dimension * $ratio;
        }

        $src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($fileName));
        $destination = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

        imagecopyresampled($destination, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

        if ($mime == "image/jpeg") {
            imagejpeg($destination, $fileName, 100);
        } else if ($mime == "image/png") {
            imagepng($destination, $fileName, 9);
        }

        imagedestroy($src);
        imagedestroy($destination);


        if (move_uploaded_file($fileName, $targetFilePath)) {
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `uploadNewsIMG()` do exactly? Can you [edit] your question and paste its code? I suppose it moves the uploaded (temporary) file so it doesn't exist anymore in your second call of the function

Comment: @brombeer I have added the function code

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that once you call:

`move_uploaded_file`

The file is gone, and you can't access it on the second try because no such file exists anymore.

What I would recommend you to do instead is just copy the image instead of moving it. This way you will be able to run this function as many times as you like.

Here is the link for this function: [PHP copy](https://www.php.net/copy).

Comment: How can you copy the image to use for resizing?

Comment: @MusHarlem I am sorry, but I don't think I understood your question. What does `move_uploaded_file` & `copy` have to do with the resizing?

Comment: The thing is, when I want to upload an image I choose the image and then it uploads it. What I want to do is also save a smaller version of that image :-) So two images are uploaded, one just as it is and the other one a bit smaller (thumbnail)

Comment: @MusHarlem Did you replace the `move_uploaded_file` with `copy` and test it? It should give you the desired result, as the error you are receiving is because on the second run there is no more image in the source path.  If you are not getting two images, one normal, and one thumbnail, then let us know, and we will try to help you